# PHP extension install - phpize error - on NGINX/PHP-FPM

Tags: php, nginx, centos, pecl

I want to install imagick extension for PHP. But i get error 'phpize' error when installing

> > pecl install imagick-3.1.2

```
downloading imagick-3.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.1.2.tgz (94,657 bytes)
.....................done: 94,657 bytes
15 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: phpize: command not found
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

I know php-devel package contains phpize for compiling/creating modules/extensions. I don't want to install apache. I am running a LEMP on CentOS 6.4

How do i proceed? or install `phpize` without apache and reinstalling/configuring php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as root, execute the following command

```
yum install php-devel
```

Then try installing the imageMagick extension again

Comment: I know that, but the problem is it includes apache and php as well. I am running php-fpm on nginx. How to proceed without affecting change on my current php configuration?

Comment: Did you install your own custom version of PHP by any chance ? Check and see if "phpize5" is available on your system and if so, symlink phpize5 -> /usr/local/bin/phpize  or something

Comment: no phpize5 isn't available. Will installing `php-devel` disrupt the current php.ini setting or config in any sense and after installing how do i remove apache?

Comment: I went ahead and installed php-devel, didn't start apache. Seems like that was the only way! :( tried too much!

Comment: Great! Now you can make sure that apache also doesn't start automatically next time you reboot by running this: chkconfig --level 345 httpd off

Answer (score 0):

Install the php-devel package, it's included in there

Comment: I know that, but the problem is it includes apache and php as well. I am running php-fpm on nginx. How to proceed without affecting change on my current php configuration?