# PHP 5.5.3 installing Imagick extension for ImageMagick

Tags: php, unix, imagick

So we have this machine with Linux running as development server.
However we are having som issue's getting the imagick extension installed.

We are using:
PHP 5.5.3 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2013 18:12:49)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

And

Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2012-05-07 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC

If we try to install imagick with this command we get the following:

```
# pecl install imagick

downloading imagick-3.1.2.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.1.2.tgz (94,657 bytes)
.....................done: 94,657 bytes
15 source files, building
running: phpize

Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

How can we do the install correct without changing our PHP version to a dev version.
Is there a version of imagick for PHP 5.5.3 or a version of imagick we can use with our PHP version.

Help would really be appreciated!

Comment: Installing the php-devel package does not change your PHP version to a "dev" version. It simply installs the development headers required to compile PHP extensions

Comment: Ok so how can we changes this to make everything work? And we want to stay on the same PHP version.

P.S. I'm super lake in using Unix. Every small explanation is very much appreciated.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19385068/php-extension-install-phpize-error-on-nginx-php-fpm

Answer (score 0):

as root, execute the following command

```
yum install php-devel
```

Then try installing the imageMagick extension again

Comment: Already tried that:

`Error: Package: php-devel-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4`

Answer (score 0):

We managed to installed the extension by removing the old php installed package because it was from a different repository. After that we installed everythings from the same repository. After that we needed to added some non default extensions back in php.ini to let everything work again! Don't know the exact details,I'm no unix expert ;).